# Algorithms (textbook) by Dasgupta. Prob. 1.36 Square Roots

Tags: logic, modulo, square-root

To begin I want to say that this is NOT a homework problem. I know stackoverflow condemns people who ask for homework solutions. I merely doing this problem out of interest.

This is the question that I am working on:

[Need help with part (b), not (a)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vSNQ.jpg)

I believe I understand (a); I had my own answer but I managed to compare my solution with a Chegg preview solution (it doesn't show part (b)). So far from my understanding of part (b) is the following:

when they say

`x is a square root of a modulo p if a = x^2(mod p)`

they mean:
 `x = sqrt(a mod p) IF a = x^2(mod p).`

Now, where it says,

if a has a square root modulo p, then `a^((p+1)/4)` is such a square root

confuses me a lot. I'm not really sure what this line means!

Comment: How is this question related to **algorithm** tag ? Please remove it if you have tagged it by mistake.

Comment: Welcome on the SO! ... You could formulate your question in a shorter way, couldn't you? If you will edit your question, I will surely upvote your question.

Comment: @RohitRawat , the book is called "Algorithms". It's written by Dasgupta, Papadimitriou and Vazirani. I can add a Book or Textbook tag if that helps.

Comment: @Gangnus , thank you for the help

Comment: @Papermate A question from book of algorithm will not be necessarily a question related to algorithm.

Comment: @Papermate  And stackoverflow don't have 'book' or 'textbook' tag. You should really read this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if a has a square root modulo p, then a^((p+1)/4) is such a square root
```

=

If there exists K such that `K^2 mod p = a`,

then

```
a^((p+1)/4) mod p = K
```

Comment: @Gangus, thank you! I find the question a little confusing still, but I'll make do with this

Comment: @Papermate 1. if you start a comment with `@` and the first letter, the system will propose you the `@name`. 2. All comments without `@name` notify the author of the post. 3. If there is only comments of one author under the post, he will be notified by the the comment of the author even without `@name` addressing. (but I often write these excessive `@name`, too  :-)) 4. Was glad to help, the question looks better now. +1. 5. If you haven't understood my answer, feel free to tell it in comments. If you need something extra, ask another quesrion. Or questions. One question per one problem.

Comment: I sincerely appreciate the patience and help! I will definitely keep in mind what you've told me. Thanks a bunch! :D